# Populate a dropdown using Linq?

Tags: asp.net-core, ienumerable, selectlist, selectlistitem

Asp.NetCore
EntityFrameWorkCore
Repository Pattern

My project builds however the dropdown display some namespace here:
[image: Dropdown display namespace code instead of commodities]

Here is my code:

Model:

```
    public partial class Commodity
    {
        public Commodity()
        {

        }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CommodityCodes { get; set; };
        [Key]
        public Guid Oid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Interface + Repository:

```
public interface ICommodityRepository
{


    IEnumerable<Commodity> ListAll();
    IEnumerable<string> GetCommodityDropDown();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements);

}

Repository:
        public IEnumerable<string> GetCommodityDropDown()
        {
            Commodity model = new Commodity();
            var commodities = from c in model.Oid.ToString()
                              select c;
            return new List<string>
            {
                commodities.ToString()

            };
        }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements)
        {
            var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = element,
                    Text = element
                });
            }

            return selectList;
        }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var codes = _commodityRepository.GetCommodityDropDown();
    var model = new Commodity();
    model.CommodityCodes = _commodityRepository.GetSelectListItems(codes);
    return View(model);
}
```

And finally my view:

```html
  <div class="form-group">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Code, Model.CommodityCodes,
 "- Please select a Commodity -",new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
```

Comment: if you're trying to implement a selectlist.. then use the SelectList constructor.. `new SelectList(context.Countries, "Oid", "Code")`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries = context.Countries.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Oid, Text = x.Code });`

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me what kind of property Countries should be? SelectListItem? Ienumerable<Commodity>??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this...

```
public interface ICommodityRepository
{
    SelectList ListAll();
}

public class CommodityRepository : ICommodityRepository
{
    private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext ();
    // Note: Your database context should define this property:
    //       public DbSet<Commodity> CommoditySet{ get; set; }

    public SelectList ListAll(){
       return new SelectList( db.CommoditySet, "Oid", "Oid" );
    }
}
Define a view model:
Note: You shouldn't use your model here. Define a view model instead 
public class CommodityViewModel
{
     public  string Code{ get; set; }
     public SelectList CommodityCodes{ get; set; } 
}

Controller:

public IActionResult Index()
{
   CommodityViewModel viewModel= new CommodityViewModel();
   viewModel.CommodityCodes= repository.ListAll();

   return View(viewModel);
}

 view:

  <div class="form-group">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Code, Model.CommodityCodes,
 "- Please select a Commodity -",new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you issac. this worked. Why do I need to pass Oid in twice as a parameter?

Comment: Hi EB, the first Oid stands for the value of the select HTML element (DropDownList), the second Oid stands for the text of the select ; that is, the value that is displayed to the user